# Functions/Synonyms in Parallel Data Warehouse

Tags: sql-server, parallel-data-warehouse

I know in PDW, functions and synonyms are not supported. Any idea, what's the alternative for these?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Synonyms - just referring to the underlying object.

Functions - sub-queries, views, or stored procedures that populate temp tables.

Answer (score 0):

The Analytics Platform System v2 Appliance Update 3 supports scalar UDF functions. You can download the [Analytics Platform System AU3 Help file](http://www.microsoft.com/download/confirmation.aspx?id=45294) for more details.

We are planning on adding synonym support in a future release.